# Is it possible to freeze the DOM in browser for drag debugging?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, web-inspector

I'm trying to debug an Angular CDK drag problem. The problem only occurs while dragging, so it would be great if I could freeze the DOM while dragging. Then I want to inspect the DOM to find analyze the problem.

Is this prossible in Browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome)?

Comment: Yes, enable the relevant event in Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints: https://puu.sh/GyK3o/e52eb6c228.png

Comment: @wOxxOm how does it work? If I select `drag` and `dragstart` nothing happens if I drag the element.

Comment: Okay, now I tried it in Firefox (before it was Chrome) and there `dragstart` works, but all other drag events not. Seems not to work reliable

Comment: I got it working. Mouse wheel event does also work in Firefox. I move the element and then I scroll to trigger the breakpoint. ^^

Comment: @wOxxOm could be please answer this question? Your comment helped me to solve my problem, so I will accept it as answer.

Comment: I think it'll be more useful to others if you post an answer yourself with your findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thx to [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the hint in the comments. Yes, it should be possible to set breakpoints for e.g. `drag` and `dragstart` events.

[image: Chrome event listener breakpoints]

The problem was those breakpoints did not worked. Only `dragstart` worked in Firefox for me, but it was to early for my DOM debugging. But I got it working using the `keyup` event in Firefox. I dragged the element and then I hit the key and then breakpoint was triggered.